# SQL Server 2008 - Data migration from old database schema(not normalized) to new database schema(normalized)

Tags: sql-server

I have a old SQL server database(in 2008 r2) with lot of denormalized tables and this has become a major hurdle to scale the application. I have normalized the database design and have come up with new database design in sql server 2008 only which has been derived from old db schema with normalizations. But as the application was live there is lot of data with old schema. What is the best way to migrate the data from old schema to new schema?

Note:- In the old schema, most of the tables dint have primary column, few of them had primary column but on varchar datatype, so in new DB schema I have added primary columns with bigint data type to all the tables.

Comment: A few things to be aware: Bigint for primary key may not be suitable for most cases. Varchar type is more flexible. Next, consider you frontend application. You need to modify it to comply with new schema. DO A LOT OF UAT BEFORE DEPLOY. That's about all from me :)

Comment: but varchar type as primary key may slow the table access, Please correct if my understanding is wrong.